# Issue with Setting Up WordPress on Local Machine using MySQL 8.0 Only

Tags: wordpress, connection, localhost, mysql-8.0

MySQL 8.0 is installed and running on my machine, and I can access to wordpress via MySQL Server
I have downloaded the latest version of WordPress and extracted it to the directory C:\Program Files\wordpress.
When I try to access http://localhost/wordpress, I receive the message "localhost refused to connect."
I am seeking assistance in resolving this issue. Are there any specific configurations needed for MySQL 8.0, and does anyone have experience with this?

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'my_wordpress' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
```

Despite configuring the wp-config.php file, attempting to access http://localhost/wordpress results in the "localhost refused to connect" error.

The server Mysql80 is running and accessible. Additionally, Jenkins has been successfully launched on port 8080.

Seeking help to identify the root cause of the connection issue. Specifically, whether additional configurations are needed for MySQL 8.0 in a WordPress setup without Apache.

Comment: wiordpress belongs under www/ depending on which web ser you are using, so asuch thing is best to use xampp where you get all in one download and lots of help from websearch